# win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData throws error when used in AWS SAML federated login

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cookies, saml, pywin32

I am trying to use AWS SAML for federal login but there is a function call below :

```
cookiesObj = getCookiesObj(
    domain=args.domain,
    username=args.username,
    cookiefile=args.cookiefile,
    useKeyring=args.keyring,
    chromeprofile=args.chromeprofile
)
```

This call goes to the below code :

```
c = sqlite3.connect(cookiefile)
        sql = "SELECT name,encrypted_value FROM cookies " + \
              "WHERE  name IN ('" + ("','".join(requiredCookies)) + "')" + \
              "AND    host_key like '%{}%'".format(domain)

        rows = c.cursor().execute(sql)
        rowCount = 0
        for k, ev in rows:
            val = None
            *val = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(ev, None, None, None, 0)[1]*
            cookiesObj['cookies'][k] = val
            rowCount += 1
```

Although the sql query returns cookies MSISAuth,MSISAuth1 with value(ev) too but the win32crypt call throws error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_saml.py", line 435, in <module>
    chromeprofile=args.chromeprofile
  File "aws_saml.py", line 251, in getCookiesObj
    val = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(ev, None, None, None, 0)[1]
pywintypes.error: (13, 'CryptProtectData', 'The data is invalid.')
```

versions used : 
pypiwin32==220 also tried with 223
pywin32==227

Comment: As far as I can found Chrome just rolled out Chrome 80 which changed cookie storing and in Chrome 79 it is working fine, so if anyone who knows the update in detail can suggest any workaround other than downgrading chrome?